# Inaccurate Minecart Rendering

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

My minecarts are cutting corners and "skipping" across turns when they're at high speeds. How can I make minecarts follow the rails more accurately when going very fast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution to this is to slow down the minecart with this rendering glitch. I've tried to figure this out myself, but I get the same results your getting every time. In simplest terms, the speed IS the cause of the glitch.